# Laravel: "$ php artisan route:list" does not show route list in App\Http\Controllers\API

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I created a `UserController` inside

`app/Http/Controllers/API/UserController.php`

Inside the UserController.php I have this
`namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;`

Inside the api.php I have this
`Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);`

I get this error below when I try to display the route list.

> Error: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\UserController] does not
>   exist.

How do we tell Laravel that the `UserController` is inside `app/Http/Controllers/API?`

Comment: What exactly would `Route::apiResources` do?

Comment: "You may register many API resource controllers at once by passing an array to the `apiResources` method:"

Reference:
[link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. I appreciate it. It turns out I made another route in web.php
`Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index')->name('user');`
causing the error. After I deleted that line, the route:list finally displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to defined the namespace, so laravel can find the controller:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
...
class UserController extends Controller {
```

You have already defined the api.php with namespace `API`:

```php
Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);
```

Try to clear the routes cache:

```sh
php artisan route:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time in answering. Where do I define the namespace?

Comment: In your UserController.php

Comment: I checked, Laravel already put the namespace there automatically. I see this

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;`

Comment: @NoOne Laravel have already put `App\Http\Controllers` without `API`, so the error occurs. make sure there is `API` in namespace.

Comment: Thank you for that. That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the path you specify is correct ?
and you could also check the namespace in the UserController, correspond to:
`namespace App\Http\Controllers\API` ?

Or also you can simply add the controllers in the wep / api routes :

`Route::get('prefix', 'DirOfYourController\YourController@SomeFunction);`

Or as stated on the documentation you could take a look here:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-group-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

Well it's definitely because one of your `web.php` or `api.php` file
make sure that namespace of the file is correct in there for instance
`Route::get('foo', 'API\UserController');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow only 2 steps to achieve the same:

**Step1:**
   Define the correct name space in your `UserController` as below

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
```

**Step2:** Define route with directory name in your `web.php` for eg.

```
 Route::get('dashboard', 'API\UserController@dashboard');
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. In the UserController I have this
`namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;`

Then in the api.php I have this
`Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);`